# How to install nvm in JailKit?

Tags: linux, shell, nvm

I am using Jailkit as described here
https://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/

And Also configured it for using NodeJS, with the help of this answer:
[Setup nodejs and npm within Jailkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949747/setup-nodejs-and-npm-within-jailkit)

But I am still confused about how to install NVM in the jailed shell!
Installation script of NVM fails inside the Jailed shell.

Comment: If I run NVM install script inside Jailed Shell, with wget it does nothing.
With curl, it gives an error as curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations